# Ping host from android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-networking

I am trying access web page hosted in my dev Ubuntu machine from android emulator. I am able to browse internet from emulator but web page from the host dev machine is not accessible, giving tcp_error. I am not able to ping the host machine too. I tried using ip address of host not localhost or 127.0.0.1.

any idea?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: I am able to access development machine using ip 10.0.2.2!

Comment: @Jibin Scaria . thanx but how can we access the device's/emulator's "http server" from the development machine? In other words, the reverse.

Comment: @Arvin Please check "Interconnecting Emulator Instances" in http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Answer (score 9):

According to Google's [official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html), `10.0.2.2` is a special alias to host loopback interface (i.e., `127.0.0.1` on your development machine).

So you can try to connect `10.0.2.2` as your host address to access your web pages from your host dev machine.

Comment: We solved with a combination of this and @matija's answeres

Answer (score 1):

you have to put this line just after android:minSdkVersion tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope it works ;)